# Redirect to previous component on button click (React Routing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-hooks

I have a react component that renders when i click on a menu option, this page has a form to complete and that's done, onSubmit i want to redirect it to the component that the user clicked before.

I tried to redirect it with Redirect and also using useHistory(), but none of them are working, this is what i did with useHistory():

The current url is `localhost/home/schemes/firstoption` and i want to fo back to `localhost/home/firstoption`.

Scheme.js:

```
  let history = useHistory();


<Button
                className="button-dc btn-block top30"
                variant="primary"
                type="submit"
                disabled={enableButton}
              >
                Finish
              </Button>
const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    {...}
    history.push(previousURL);
  };
  const URL = window.location.href;
  const previousURL = URL.split("scheme/").join("");
  previousURL // localhost/home/firstoption
```

This creates this URL but doesn't redirect:

```
https://localhost/home/scheme/https://localhost/home/firstoption
```

And i also tried to do the same thing but instead of using

```
history.push(previousURL);
```

I used this:

```
return <Redirect to={previousURL} />
```

And this doesn't create the URL and doesn't redirect either.

Does anyone see any error on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make any of the suggested options work, so i ended up doing this:

```
window.history.pushState({}, null, previousURL); // previousURL = localhost/home/firstoption
location.reload();
```

I hope this also helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

In order to redirect you can use the method push of history

```
history.push({
    pathname:'yourpathname',
})
```

Or you can simpy wrap your button with Link from react-router-dom :

```
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

    <Link to="pathname">
    <Button
                    className="button-dc btn-block top30"
                    variant="primary"
                  >
                    Finish
                  </Button>
    </Link>
```

the issue is in the pathname that you wrote, the pathname it's relative to the application home page route and not the full URL

Comment: The link appends previousURL to the current one, so i will have this: https://localhost/home/scheme/https://localhost/home/firstoption. And i tried to use pathname   like this: history.push({
    pathname:{previousURL},
}); but it's not working either

Comment: Link is related to the app url (defined by / )  <Link to=''/home/firstoption/'> 
The pathname must be always relative to the application path, not the full URL